# ORA-01008: not all variables bound when using JdbcTempate

Tags: spring, oracle

I am running a simple insert using jdbcTemplate version 4 and getting:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

here is the insert:

```
    int[] ret = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO BATCH_JOBS_TABLE (JOB_STATUS, CREATE_BY) VALUES (?,?)", "ACTIVE","USER_ADMIN");
```

stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during batching: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:5043)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:246)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:561)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:548)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:408)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: where is the code ? you had to add 2 parameters

Comment: Why are you using `batchUpdate` for something that isn't a batch update?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] ret = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO BATCH_JOBS_TABLE (JOB_STATUS, CREATE_BY) VALUES (?,?)", "ACTIVE","USER_ADMIN");
```

The last 2 parameters of the call should be SQL.

From javadoc

```
/**
 * Issue multiple SQL updates on a single JDBC Statement using batching.
 * <p>Will fall back to separate updates on a single Statement if the JDBC
 * driver does not support batch updates.
 * @param sql defining an array of SQL statements that will be executed.
 * @return an array of the number of rows affected by each statement
 * @throws DataAccessException if there is any problem executing the batch
 */
int[] batchUpdate(String... sql) throws DataAccessException;
```

so you need to pass parameters not just add them in the call.